# Indexing coordinates in MongoDB not working

Tags: ruby, mongodb, indexing, sinatra, mongoid

I have a model that stores coordinates and the coordinates are indexed

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

  field :coordinates, type: Array, spacial: true

  index({ coordinates: "2d" }, { unique: true })
end
```

However, whenever I save a place with a set of coordinates then create another, both coordinates are saved. This leads me to believe that the indexing of coordinates are not working. What am I missing here and how can I fix it?

An example below.

```
place = Place.new(coordinates: [50, 50])

place.save # returns true in console

place2 = Place.new(coordinates: [50, 50])

place2.save # returns true in console

# Thus I have two place records with the same exact coordinates, something I don't want
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Put it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2d and 2dsphere index types don't enforce the **unique** constraint at all. I've created a DOCS issue to clarify this in the documentation: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-1701

Comment: Cool thanks. I hope that is currently the case. Upon further research it looks like Mongoid, the ODM I'm using requires a rake task to perform the indexing, however, there is no explanation on how to do such a thing for a Sinatra app. Thanks for the answer and help in reporting the issue to MongoDB.